# HTML5 Drag and drop not working as expected on Angular 6

Tags: angular, html

I'm trying to implement a very simple drag and drop feature to an Angular 6 app, but I'm having some troubles I wasn't expecting.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w7lupc

And the problems I'm facing:

On Chrome, setting the dragged data on the `dragstart` event, handled by the method `itemDragStart`, using `e.dataTransfer.setData('itemData', JSON.stringify(item));` does nothing. This works as expected on Firefox:

[image: Differences between Chrome and Firefox]

Also, the `drop` event handler is never called, neither on Chrome nor on Firefox. This is the template markup with the event handlers definition:

```
<div class="container" #dropContainer
  (dragenter)="dragEnter($event)"
  (dragleave)="dragLeave($event)"
  (drop)="dragDrop($event)">
```

The method `dragDrop` is never called, strangely `dragLeave` is called instead when dropping the boxes into the container.

What's wrong with the code? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just by chance, I found a similar question on Stackoverflow with the solution:

[HTML 5 Drag & Drop with Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47975237/html-5-drag-drop-with-angular-4)

It's as simple as adding a `dragover` event handler on the drop container with the following code:

```
listDragOver(e: DragEvent) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this piece of code it works.

```
 public ondragover(event: Event): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();     
  }
  public ondrop(event): void {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();  

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `draggable="true"` to the dragging element.

```
  <div #dragElement
      (drag)="drag($event)"
      (dragstart)="dragStart($event)"
      (dragend)="dragEnd($event)"
      draggable="true">
```